# How to render python code using Mathjax?

Tags: python, latex, mathjax

I want to use python code using Mathjax ? I tried below code but it is not rendering python, but it is rendering mathematical equations.

You can test in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/xepevowive/edit?html,output).

The same code is shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MathJax TeX Test Page</title>
<!-- <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
</script> -->

<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
          MathJax.Hub.Config({
            TeX: {extensions:["mhchem.js"]},
            jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
            tex2jax: {
                    inlineMath: [["$","$"],["\\(","\\)"]]
            },
            "HTML-CSS": { preferredFont: "TeX", availableFonts: ["STIX","TeX"] },
             processEscapes: true
        });
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>

</head>
<body>
When $a \ne 0$, there are two solutions to \(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\) and they are
$$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$

<pre>
~~
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((1, 2))
~~
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen exactly?

Comment: Is it used to render python ?

Comment: MathJax does not render python code. Though I'm not sure if that's what you are asking.

Comment: Ok, I saw some where rending python code. May be its different one, sorry. thanks

Comment: Check out Jupyter / IPython notebooks.

Comment: ok thanks..................

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Google Code Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) to render the Python code and use Mathjax to render the mathematical equations.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MathJax TeX Test Page</title>

<!--Google Code Prettify script tag-->
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>

<!-- <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
</script> -->

<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
          MathJax.Hub.Config({
            TeX: {extensions:["mhchem.js"]},
            jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
            tex2jax: {
                    inlineMath: [["$","$"],["\\(","\\)"]]
            },
            "HTML-CSS": { preferredFont: "TeX", availableFonts: ["STIX","TeX"] },
             processEscapes: true
        });
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>

</head>
<body>
When $a \ne 0$, there are two solutions to \(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\) and they are
$$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$

<!--Google Code Prettify usage-->
<pre class="prettyprint">
~~
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((1, 2))
~~
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```